# Get user input with multple values formated with comma

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to achive someting like this:
User input values here for example 1,2,3

```
Your values: 1,2,3 [1,2,3 is inputed by user in one line]
```

and this values are pushed to array.I need check here if number is not bigger than max number for example 4 and isnt below 1.

I came up with this code. It takes msg to show for user and max num,but as you can see it only can return single value and i have no idea how to modify it to work as i discribed it.

```
const int getMultipleIntAboveZero(const std::string &msg,int maxNum){
  int num;
  std::cout<< msg;
  while(!(std::cin>>num)|| num < 1 || num > maxNum){
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout<<"\nInvalid input. Try again: ";
  }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: `return num;` only returns a single integer. Maybe you really wanted `std::vector<int> getMultipleIntAboveZero(const std::string &msg,int maxNum){` which will allow 0 or more integers to be returned.

Comment: create an `std::vector<int>` variable inside your function, fill it with `push_back()` and return it

Comment: There is no confusion on what you want to do.  This should be pretty easy code to write for anyone with a few weeks experience in c++.  With that said I am not sure you made a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself especially given the 2 comments so I will not answer: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) you may have to search some more. There will be questions here that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How can I get integer array inputted by user with commas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector< int > getMultipleIntAboveZero(std::string msg, int maxNum) {
    std::istringstream iss (msg);
    std::string unit;
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int num;

    while(std::getline(iss, unit, ',')) {
    num = std::stoi(unit);
        if (num >= 1 && num <= maxNum) {
            std::cout << num << '\n';
        nums.push_back(num);
        } else {
            std::cout<<"Invalid input. Try again\n";
        }
    }
  return nums;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Your values: ");
    std::string msg;
    std::cin >> msg;
    getMultipleIntAboveZero(msg, 4);
}
```